# make this sql query faster or use pl sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So the below query on an oracle server takes around an hour to execute.
Is it a way to make it faster?

```
SELECT * 
FROM ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca1 
WHERE aca1.ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE='021' 
  AND aca1.ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE='R12' 
  AND aca1.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT='999'   
  AND 
  EXISTS   
  (
      SELECT 'a' 
      FROM ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca2     
      WHERE  aca1.account_id = aca2.account_id 
        AND aca2.ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE='021'  
        AND aca2.ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE='R12' 
        AND aca2.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT ='1' 
        AND aca2.cycle_activity_amount > 25
        AND  (aca2.cycle_ctr > aca1.cycle_ctr) 
        AND aca2.cycle_ctr =  
        (
            SELECT MIN(cycle_ctr) 
            FROM ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca3 
            WHERE aca3.account_id = aca1.account_id 
              AND aca3.ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE='021'  
              AND aca3.ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE='R12' 
              AND aca3.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT ='1' 
       )
  );
```

So basically this is what  it is trying to do. 
Find a row with a R12, 021 and 999 value,
for all those rows we have to make sure another row exist with the same account id, but with R12, 021 and count = 1.
If it does we have to make sure that the amount of that row is > 25 and the cycle_ctr counter of that row is the smallest.

As you can see we are doing repetition while doing  a select on MIN(CYCLE_CTR).

EDIT: There is one index define on ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY table's column ACCOUNT_ID.

Our table is ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY. If there is a row with ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE = '021' and ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE = 'R12' and CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT = '999', that represents the identity row.

If an account with an identity row like that has other 021 R12 rows, query for the row with the lowest CYCLE_CTR value that is greater than the CYCLE_CTR from the identity row. If a row is found, and the CYCLE_ACTIVITY_AMOUNT of the row found is > 25 and CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT = 1, report the account.

Note that identity row is just for identification and will not be reported.

For example, this a SELECT on a account_id which should be reported.

```
  Account_ID    Group_Code  Type_code   Cycle_ctr   Activity_Amount Activity_count
 53116267       R12          021       14          0               999
 53116267       R12          021       25          35              1
 53116267       R12          021       22          35              1
 53116267       R12          021       20          35              1
```

There are several other Activity_count apart from 999 and 1, so a WHERE clause for that is necessary.

Similarly if the above example was like following

```
 Account_ID     Group_Code  Type_code   Cycle_ctr   Activity_Amount Activity_count
     53116267       R12          021       14          0               999
     53116267       R12          021       25          35              1
     53116267       R12          021       22          35              1
     53116267       R12          021       20         **20**           1
```

It wouldnt be reported because the activity_amount of the row with the lowest cycle_ctr greater than the cycle_ctr of the identity row is 20, which is less than 25.

Explain plan after

```
      explain plan for select * from account_activity;
      select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1692077632

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                  |   470M|    12G|   798K  (1)| 02:39:38 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION HASH ALL        |                  |   470M|    12G|   798K  (1)| 02:39:38 |     1 |    64 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY |   470M|    12G|   798K  (1)| 02:39:38 |     1 |    64 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or not?

Comment: Yes, Oracle owns MySQL, but Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: Which indexes have you already created so far?

Comment: Oracle, and SQL Developer :P)

Comment: No indexes allowed? Why not?

Comment: There is lots of repetions in the queries, is there a way to remove them?

Comment: We developers dont have authority to create indexes. We can create a pl/sql though.

Comment: Show us an explain plan please

Comment: this query would be executed on a database which is not owned by us. We would have to get permission first for indexes.

Comment: Just because you can't *create* indexes doesn't mean that there aren't any *already defined*.  You need to understand a database's indexing in order to use it efficiently.  You also need to understand the cardinality of those indexes.  Until you provide that information, I really don't see how anyone can really help—except by stabbing in the dark and hoping for the best.

Comment: Isnt it possible through a simple sql without indexes?

Comment: Ok let me see what indexes are already there, and if possible to define other.

Comment: So seems like you guys were correct! There is an index on ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY Table on the column ACCOUNT_ID.

Comment: I'm almost certain you can rephrase this query to be more efficient.  The problem is, I can't follow the rules you are trying to apply.  Can you edit the question with sample data and desired results?  What does it mean to say "but with R12, 021 and count = 1"?  What is "the amount of that row"?

Comment: ok sure, let me do that.

Comment: How much data is on the table?    How much data gets selected? for '021' and 'r12'?

Comment: Please show us the explain plan.

Comment: More than 20k of rows come if i do a select on '021' and 'r12'

Comment: Im sorry for my ignorance, but i have no clue what is an explain plan?

Comment: Google is your friend.  Explain plans will give you a clue as to what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, just added the explain plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the query using explicit joins, and not with EXISTS.

Basically these two lines

```
WHERE  aca1.account_id = aca2.account_id 
AND  (aca2.cycle_ctr > aca1.cycle_ctr)
```

are the join condition for joining the first and second select, and this one joins the first and the third.

```
WHERE aca3.account_id = aca1.account_id
```

The query should look like this

```
select distinct aca1.*
FROM ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca1, ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca2, ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca3
WHERE
 join conditions and other selection conditions
```

Comment: This is the one.   The with statement lets you filter out a lot of data early.   The joins though are where you are likelty to get the speed you are looking for    +1 dimm

Comment: Did that, and executing however, aca3 has to be nested, because we need to find the min(cycle_ctr) aca2.cycle_ctr =  (SELECT MIN(cycle_ctr) FROM ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca3 and other conditions);

Comment: Yes! By replacing with joins it ran in 40 mins! So i believe the issue was with EXIST we were searching exponentialy, however by doing a JOIN we searched after multiplying. Sorry i cant vote any of you, since my reputation is not 15.

Comment: FYI, though it seems to have worked in this case, it is not always the case that replacing `EXISTS` with explicit joins will speed up the query. It's worth trying, but a good rule of thumb is to use `EXISTS` when you don't need columns from the tables referenced in the subquery, and joins when you do.

Comment: Also, I am waiting for someone to weigh in on the fact that you didn't use ANSI joins ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would probably start with use of the WITH statement to hopefully reduce the number of times that the data is selected, and make it more readable.  The other thing i would recommend is replacing the exists by some sort of join.

```
with base as 
(
    select *
    from account_cycle_activity
    where activity_type_code = '021'
      and activity_group_code = 'R12'
)
SELECT * 
FROM base aca1 
WHERE aca1.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT='999'   
  AND 
  EXISTS   
  (
      SELECT 'a' 
      FROM base aca2     
      WHERE  aca1.account_id = aca2.account_id 
        AND aca2.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT ='1' 
        AND aca2.cycle_activity_amount > 25
        AND  (aca2.cycle_ctr > aca1.cycle_ctr) 
        AND aca2.cycle_ctr =  
        (
            SELECT MIN(cycle_ctr) 
            FROM base aca3 
            WHERE aca3.account_id = aca1.account_id 
              AND aca3.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT ='1' 
       )
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, I am executing this currently. My version took around 1 hr 20 min to finish. Let see how long this takes. I am sure it will be much lesser.

Comment: Just curious, if we bring the PL/SQL into equation, wouldnt decision making and breaking the logic make it more easier and efficient by making this into a procedure?

Comment: It may run longer.      In general, if you can do it in a query, do it in a query.     It will usually run faster than procedural code.

Answer (score 1):

My rewrite of the query is this:

```
Select  Aca1.* 
From    Account_Cycle_Activity Aca1
Join    Account_Cycle_Activity Aca2
    On  Aca2.Account_Id = Aca1.Account_Id
    And Aca2.Group_Code = Aca1.Group_Code
    And Aca2.Type_Code  = Aca1.Type_Code
    And Aca2.Activity_Amount > 25
    And Aca2.Activity_Count = 1
    And Aca2.Cycle_Ctr > Aca1.Cycle_Ctr
    And Aca2.Cycle_Ctr =(
            Select  Min( Cycle_Ctr ) 
            From    Account_Cycle_Activity Aca3 
            Where   Aca3.Account_Id = Aca1.Account_Id 
              And   Aca3.Type_Code  = Aca1.Type_Code 
              And   Aca3.Group_Code = Aca1.Group_Code
              And   Aca3.Activity_Count =1 
       )
Where Aca1.Type_Code    = 21
  And Aca1.Group_Code   = 'R12' 
  And Aca1.Activity_Count = 999;
```

But the execution plan wasn't all that different and, more significantly, the cost, 14, was the same. However, then I added the two indexes and the cost fell from 14 to 2. I tried to create a Fiddle but, as usual, the Oracle section was inoperative. So here it is:

```
Create Table Account_Cycle_Activity(
    Account_Id      Int Not Null,
    Group_Code      Char( 3 ) Not Null,
    Type_Code       Int Not Null,
    Cycle_Ctr       Int Not Null,
    Activity_Amount Int Not Null,
    Activity_Count  Int Not Null
);

insert into Account_Cycle_Activity
    select  53116267, 'R12', 21, 14, 0, 999 from dual union all
    select  53116267, 'R12', 21, 25, 35,  1 from dual union all
    Select  53116267, 'R12', 21, 22, 35,  1 From Dual Union All
    select  53116267, 'R12', 21, 20, 35,  1 from dual;

-- Execute the query before creating these indexes and again after.
Create Index Ix_Account_Cycle_Activity1
    On Account_Cycle_Activity( Account_Id, Group_Code, Type_Code, Activity_Amount, Activity_Count );
Create Index Ix_Account_Cycle_Activity2
    On Account_Cycle_Activity( Cycle_Ctr );
```